# Is there an implementation of lsqlin () in Eigen?

Tags: eigen

I'm looking for [lsqlin()](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html?lang=en) implimatation in Eigen.
I read official documents, but did't find equivalent.

Is there any equivalent? or I have to extend Eigen::LeastSquaresConjugateGradient ?

I wrote like following.

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A;
Eigen::VectorXd b;
// fill A and b
...
// want x[i] in [0,1], but not...
Eigen::LeastSquaresConjugateGradient<Eigen::MatrixXd> solver;
solver.compute(A);
auto x = solver.solve(b);
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Comment: added code. I forgot to say, matrix is sparse(10^6 x 10^5) and few non-zero elements per column.

Comment: I find Eigen::internal::constrained_cg, but I don't know how to use...  

`IterationController ite;`  
`Eigen::internal::constrained_cg(A, C, x, b, f, ite);`  
  
Above causes row()/column() mismatch....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no. you have to use the SVD decomposition or the QR decomposition

Comment: I cant figure out, how to apply  Inequality constraints.